# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n^2-1}.$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> So I need to use the fourier series of $f(x)=|\sin(x)|$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ to compute the
>   sums $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}\tag1,$$
>   $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n^2-1}.\tag2$$

I correctly obtained the Fourier series to be

$$|\sin(x)|=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}\cos(2xn)\tag3.$$

To compute sum $(1)$ I used the theorem that states that the series converges to the average of the left and right hand limits of points of discontinuity, like for example $\pi.$  So

$$\frac{|\sin(\pi)|+|\sin(-\pi)|}{2}=0=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}\cos(2\pi n)\Leftrightarrow (1)=\frac{1}{2},$$

by solving for the sum and since $\cos(2\pi n)=1 \ \forall \ n \ \in \mathbb{N.}$ But I can't apply the same method to compute the sum number $(2).$

does anyone have a suggestion on how one could proceed here?

Comment: A useful identity is $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have just used the value of $x=0$ in both sides of the equation for (1). For (2), try inputting $x=\pi/2$ then the left hand side is $1$ and the right hand side is the required summation.